# RestKit Linking Error When Archiving for Ad Hoc

Tags: ios, linker-errors, restkit

I'm using RestKit and the app runs fine in debug mode but when I try to create a archive I get a whole bunch of linking error:

_RKRequestCacheDateHeaderKey has different visibility (default) in ... /Release-iphoneos/theCamera.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ClientListViewController.o

_RKRequestCacheHeadersExtension has different visibility (default) in .../Release-iphoneos/theCamera.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ClientListViewController.o

_RKRequestCacheMIMETypeKey has different visibility (default) in .../Release-iphoneos/theCamera.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ClientListViewController.o
.
.
.
Can anybody help me with it?

Thanks

Comment: Warnings went away after I put in "-fvisibility=default" under Other C Flags for RestKit project setting.

Comment: since you've solved it, put your solution as an answer, not a comment. (might need to add extra text just so it can be entered as an answer.) Then, 48 hours after you asked the original question, you can mark yours as the accepted answer. This helps out searchers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. Here's how:

1. In the Project Navigator choose RestKit.xcodeproj
2. Select ResKit under PROJECT
3. Choose Build Settings
4. Search for Other C Flags
5. Enter -fvisibility=hidden